# Java KeyBindings with JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, key-bindings

I would like to add Key bindings to my `JFileChooser` in order to open a file preview window when the SPACE key is pressed.

Because of the source code is too big, I just did a simple dirty code :

**MainWindow.java**

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {    
    public MainWindow() {
        this.setTitle("Test Window");
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(800, 600);
        this.setSize(dim);
        this.setPreferredSize(dim);

        MainPanel pane = new MainPanel(dim);

        Action damned = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "It Works !");
            }
        };

        pane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "damned");
        pane.getActionMap().put("damned", damned);

        this.setContentPane(pane);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**MainPanel.java**

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainPanel extends JFileChooser { 
    public MainPanel(Dimension dim) {  
        this.setSize(dim);
        this.setPreferredSize(dim);    
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
package test;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainWindow();
    }
}
```

If I use a JPanel instead of a JFileChooser, it works.

Thank you,

Revan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is the type of InputMap: by default (that is without parameter), that's WHEN_FOCUSED. As the chooser itself is rarely focused, the binding will not be found. Instead bind in WHEN_ANCESTOR...

```
       pane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
           .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F1"), "damned");
```

As you see here, I replaced the SPACE by F1: the space is needed (and thus eaten) by the textfield which takes the name input

Comment: What if you wanted to replace the SPACE key anyway?  How could you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to override method

```
protected JDialog createDialog(Component parent)
```

and add your action
to the dialog obtained from

```
super.createDialog(...)

dialog.getContentPane();
```