# Create a keyboard shortcut for a button

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JTable` that has a delete button to delete its rows.

I want to create a shortcut, for example when user selects a row and presses the 'Delete' button on keyboard , that line should be deleted.

My line is deleted with my `JButton1` perfectly.

```
        if (e.getSource() == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) {

           // Delete row Method
    }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240355/java-keybindings-with-jfilechooser maybe the answers help you.

Comment: Interesting that doesn't work. What about: public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){if(e.getKeyCode()==46){//method }}   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is the exact problem because you provide too few code. However, you can't use `getSource()` to test which key is typed (pressed, or released). Use `getKeyChar()` and `getKeyCode()`.

---

The following is explanation of my code:

1. You need to add a `KeyListener` to a component(of course)
2. The component must have focus

   1. The component must be focusable (set focusable to true)
   2. The component need to request for focus
3. Override `keyTyped` `keyPressed` or `keyReleased` to retrieve `KeyEvent`

   1. To check which key is typed in `keyTyped`, use `getKeyChar()`
   2. To check which key is pressed or released in `keyPressed` and `keyReleased`, use `getKeyCode()`

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(new Dimension(410, 330));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panel.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 200);

        panel.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener()); // add KeyListener
        panel.setFocusable(true); // set focusable to true
        panel.requestFocusInWindow(); // request focus

        f.getContentPane().add(panel);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyChar() == '\177') {
                // delete row method (when "delete" is typed)
                System.out.println("Key \"Delete\" Typed");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) {
                // delete row method (when "delete" is pressed)
                System.out.println("Key \"Delete\" Pressed");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) {
                // delete row method (when "delete" is released)
                System.out.println("Key \"Delete\" Released");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- don't to use KeyListener for this job, and in Swing never, use KeyBindings instead
- add ListSelectionListener to JTable, notice to test `if(table.getSelectedRow > 0)`
- use KeyBindings for JTable, override Delete key

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to this page:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/341332/GUI/java/setting-keyboard-navigation-shortcut-keys

Taken from there:

Create a key listener for that button  (it seems you have already made that):

```
Button btn = new Button("Press Me");
btn.addKeyListener(myKeyListener);
```

And implement the keylistener:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE ){
        //Do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Try it and tell me if it works.